# Why is function overload ambiguous, but template overloads not ambiguous?

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

Why, in the below, is the call to an instantiation of `bar` not ambiguous, while the non-template overloaded function `foo` is ambiguous. It is the same for `nullptr` instead of `NULL`

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void bar (T*)
{
  std::cout << "bar(T*)" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void bar (typename T::value_type *)
{
  std::cout << "bar(T::value_type*)" << std::endl;
}

struct A
{
  using value_type = int;
};

void foo (A::value_type*)
{
  std::cout << "foo(A::value_type *)" << std::endl; 
}

void foo (A*)
{
  std::cout << "foo(A *)" << std::endl; 
}

int main ()
{
  bar<A> (NULL);
  foo (NULL); // ambigous
}
```

EDIT: To be clear. I expect the `foo` overload to be ambiguous. I don't understand why the `bar` overloads generated when I instantiate `bar<A>` are not equally ambiguous.

Comment: I am surprised because I specify A as the type, which I would expect to generate two overloads for `bar`, one taking an A* and one taking an int*, the same as with `foo`. Why would one be preferred over the other? Especially in the case of `nullptr`

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Explicitly specifying the type just means there's no template type deduction happening - it doesn't mean that it can't be ambiguous.

Comment: I find it odd that this was closed by the same person who posted an answer to it just moments before...

Answer (score 1):

The rules for determining which overload is the best viable candidate as the last tiebreaker include, from [over.match.best]:

> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function
>   F2 if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then
>   — [...]
>   — F1 and F2 are function template specializations, and the function template for F1 is more specialized
>   than the template for F2 according to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.6.2.

That bullet point is reached only if we have two functions with identical conversion sequences in which either both are or both aren't function templates. For `foo`, both our overload candidates have identical conversion sequences, neither are function templates, and this last bullet point doesn't apply - so it's ambiguous.

For `bar` though, we can try to see if one or the other of

```
template<typename T> void bar (T*) // (1)
template<typename T> void bar (typename T::value_type *) // (2)
```

is more partially specialized than the other. The rules for that are basically to try to see if you can call one function with the other's argument. In this case, any `typename T::value_type*` is still a pointer, so you could call the `T*` overload with it. However, in the other direction, template deduction would fail as `typename T::value_type` is a non-deduced context. So `(2)` is considered more partially specialized and so it's chosen as the best viable candidate. No ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

There's an additional rule when it comes to resolving ambiguity between function overloads that are instantiations of a function template: *partial ordering of overloaded function templates* (**[temp.func.order]**).

This is usually used to resolve ambiguity in favor of more specialized overloaded function templates:

```
template<typename T> void f(T) { ... }
template<typename T> void f(T*) { ... } // specialization for pointers
void g() { int i; f(&i); }   // calls f<int>(int*), not f<int*>(int*)
```

However, because of the way the rules are set out (**[over.match.best]**/1) function template partial ordering applies even when the template parameter (here `T := A`) was not deduced from the arguments by template argument deduction, even if it was supplied by explicit specialization:

> [...]
>   — `F1` and `F2` are function template specializations, and the function template for `F1` is more specialized
>   than the template for `F2` according to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.6.2.

Here `bar(A::value_type *)` is considered more specialized than `bar(A *)` (under **[temp.func.order]**), so the former is preferred and there is no ambiguity.